# Click lag and typing woes in flash when rendered with JxBrowser

Tags: java, flash, chromium, jxbrowser

There're three, possibly related issues, that we've experienced in JxBrowser -

1.) Typing inside an input box inside the flash window doesn't work in JavaFx but works fine in Swing. This seems to be mostly a focus related issue.

2.) If a flash input box is clicked, then there's a noticeable lag after each keystroke. This ruins the user experience.

3.) Copy paste inside flash doesn't work when caps-lock key is on.

Are there any work-around for the above mentioned issues ? We've tried 6.1, 6.5, 6.6 and 6.7 versions and all have the same issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you try to enable heavyweight rendering mode in JxBrowser. Maybe you use lightweight rendering mode that runs Flash off-screen, so it might behave differently causing this slowness.

Comment: The browser is already running in heavyweight mode. Lag is observed only in typing, performance seems to be fine otherwise. And what about the other issues  like copy-paste ?

Comment: If you use heavyweight rendering mode, then Chromium engine is the one who is responsible for how the Flash is embedded and work. JxBrowser 6.7.1 is based on Chromium 51. I believe if you load the web page with this Flash in Google Chrome 51, you will see the same issues. Maybe you can provide me with URL that I can use to reproduce these issues?